# Randomly remove elements from an array until empty

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to randomly select an element inside an Array, then remove that element from the Array *until there is no element left* inside that Array.

I have been trying to use the `.filter()` function and some `Math.random` but it still didn't work. Also, I tried putting it inside `for()` but none of the ways I tried worked.

Comment: Show us the code from your attempts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var days = ['monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday'];
const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * days.length);
console.log(days[random]); //prints the random item

var value = days[random]
days = days.filter(function(item) {
  return item !== value
})

console.log(days) //prints the array after removing the random item
```

Answer (score 2):

You can generate a random index each time and use `Array#splice`.

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
function getRand(){
  return arr.splice(Math.random() * arr.length | 0, 1)[0];
}
console.log(getRand());
console.log(arr);
```

For your intended use case, though, you would be better off just shuffling the array and iterating through it. The Fisher-Yates shuffle is one algorithm for doing this.

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
for(let i = arr.length - 1; i > 0; i--){
  const j = Math.random() * (i + 1) | 0;
  [arr[i], arr[j]] = [arr[j], arr[i]];
}
for(const x of arr) console.log(x);
```

Comment: This is the functional and recommended way of doing it. [`Array.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) is a powerful method to meet the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

`.filter()` makes a whole new array, it doesn't mutate the original.